# Auto adjust zoom of images in `ListView` to fit all ie., maximise their size while having no scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a view `IntroView` that contains a `ListView`, with images inside, and a possibility to zoom (resize every single image (or more specifically the `UserControl`)), determined by the dependency property `ThumbZoom` (in the code behind of `IntroView`).

I'm trying to have adjusted automatically the `ThumbZoom` value so all images inside fit the `ListView` dimensions (it self inside a resizable window).

[This option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591478/scale-images-in-listview-to-fit) for a similar problem does not work: when the overflow (the vertical scrollbar is visible) happens, switching the visibility only makes the scroll bar disappear, but does not change the `ThumbZoom`. How to achieve this ?

The xaml of `IntroView` has in particular:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Column="0"  BorderThickness="0"
          Background="Transparent"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RawImagesCollectionView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="shutterLib:RawImageViewModel">
            <intro:RawImageControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and has in code behind the dependency property `ThumbZoom`:

```
    public double ThumbZoom
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ThumbZoomProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThumbZoomProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThumbZoomProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ThumbZoom", typeof(double), typeof(IntroView),
            new PropertyMetadata(_minZoom));
```

The `UserControl` invoked receives the image and looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Senso.ShutterModeler.UI.Intro.RawImageControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Senso.ShutterModeler.UI"
             xmlns:shutterLib="clr-namespace:ShutterLib;assembly=ShutterLib"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=shutterLib:RawImageViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid Margin="5" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100">
        <Rectangle Fill="DimGray"
                   MaxWidth="{Binding ThumbZoom, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ui:IntroView}}}"
                   MaxHeight="{Binding ThumbZoom, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ui:IntroView}}}">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="11" Color="{StaticResource DropShadow}" />
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
        <Viewbox
            MaxWidth="{Binding ThumbZoom, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ui:IntroView}}}"
            MaxHeight="{Binding ThumbZoom, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ui:IntroView}}}">
            <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Vignette, IsAsync=false}" MouseMove="Vignette_OnMouseMove" />
        </Viewbox></Grid></UserControl>
```

The problem to solve (with few conditions: no margins around the image (to simplify), and a 1:2 aspect ratio) is put like this:

[image]

Which after plotting, has this aspect (for a given `T` and `Ha` `Wa` of `ScrollViewer`):

[image]

Which is good news: this minimum exists, and can be resolved by bisection.
On the left of the solution, the size of the images is too small to fill `ListView`, the jumps correspond to a change of the number of images per row. On the right of the solution, the size of the images it too big and triggers the appearance of the vertical scrollbar.

Unfortunately, depending on the aspect (`ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`) of `ScrollViewer`, the solution is visually correct only sometimes. It seems that the size of the `ScrollViewer` embedded in `ListView` has an aspect that is not a match with the visual aspect of `ListView`. In the aspect conditions (`Ha` `Wa`), the plot show an optimal zoom of 427, but there is a scrollbar, and manually I find the solution around 378. Adding the margins in the equation does not really help to improve the result (it improves the solution of only few pixels (~5), the delta is about 70 pixels).

**Which so far I do not understand. This is where I need some help.**

I used `new ScrollViewer {RenderSize = new Size(1558, 1281) }` for the plot.

The code to solve the problem is:

```
    private double _minZoom = 200.0;
    private double _maxZoom = 900.0;
    private int _totalCount = 17; // total number of images to show in listview.

    /// <summary>
    /// Size of semi-range of solution. 
    /// </summary>
    public double BallRadius { get; set; } = 1e-6;
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of steps needed to find optimal zoom.
    /// </summary>
    public int StepCount { get; protected set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Best zoom, where images are a big as possible, while no scrollbar appears.
    /// </summary>
    public double ZoomFitall => SolveMin(x => Deriv(DistZZbis, x));

    /// <summary>
    /// Solve minimum of func in [_minZoom, _maxZoom] with bisection method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="func"></param>
    /// <returns>optimal zoom</returns>
    public double SolveMin(Func<double, double> func)
    {
        int stepCount = 0;
        double l = _minZoom;
        double r = _maxZoom;
        
        bool IsMinInThisRange(double a, double b) => func(a) * func(b) < 0;
        double GetMiddle(double a, double b) => (a + b) / 2.0;
        double IntervalWidth(double a, double b) => Abs(a - b);

        while (IntervalWidth(l, r) > BallRadius)
        {
            stepCount++;
            double m = GetMiddle(l, r);
            if (IsMinInThisRange(l, m))
                r = m;
            else
                l = m;
        }

        StepCount = stepCount;
        return l;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate derivative of <c>func<c/> at <c>x0</c> over interval of <c>2dx</c>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="func">for fitall, use DistZZbis</param>
    /// <param name="x0">deriveative at x0</param>
    /// <param name="dx">infinitesimal semi-interval over x</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double Deriv(Func<double, double> func, double x0, double dx = 1e-6)
    {
        var left = func(x0 - dx);
        var right = func(x0 + dx);
        return right - left;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate distance between <c>zoom</c> and <c>zoom bis</c> as described in FindFitAll.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="z"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public double DistZZbis(double z) => Abs(z - Zbis(z));

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate zoom bis.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="z"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private double Zbis(double z) => 2 * _scroll.ActualHeight / Ceiling(_totalCount / Floor(_scroll.ActualWidth / z));
```